# Concatinating and selecting rows from two dataframes based on conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have two DataFrames like this:

```
df_cells = pd.DataFrame({
    'left': [1095, 257],
    'top': [1247, 1148],
    'right': [1158, 616],
    'bottom': [1273, 1176] 
})

df_text = pd.DataFrame({
    'words': ['Hello', 'world', 'nice day', 'have a'],
    'left': [1097, 1099, 258, 259],
    'top': [1248, 1249, 1156, 1153],
    'right': [1154, 1156, 615, 614],
    'bottom': [1269, 1271, 1175, 1172] 
})
```

`df_cells` contains coordinates of bounding boxes for phrases on an image and `df_text` contains words and their bounding box coordinates on an image. I want to combine the two DataFrames into a third DataFrame where the words from `df_text` that fall into a bbox in `df_cell` are concatinated into a phrase, along with it the bbox coordinates for the phrase from `df_text` are also displayed based on the following condition:

```
[(df_text['left'] >= df_cells['left']) & (df_text['top'] >= df_cells['top']) & (df_text['right'] <= df_cells['right']) & (df_text['bottom'] <= df_cells['bottom'])]
```

The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
Words                left    top    right   bottom
Hello world          1095    1247   1158    1273
Have a nice day      257     1148   616     1176
```

I would appreciate some help.

**Edit**: It is not necessary that multiple words always fall into a cell, sometimes it could be just one word in a bounding box.

Comment: How can you sort the words? Like, "nice day have a" or "have a nice day".

Comment: Based on the position of the left , top, right, bottom values. They are basically pixels on an image.

Comment: "have a nice day" is what i require.

Comment: What's the priority for each position? Lowest "top" and "left" value comes first?

Comment: Yes, thats it exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `function` then use `apply` to apply that function for each row.

```
def filter_text(left, top, right, bottom, df=df_text, **unuse):
    df = df.copy()

    # Based on given conditions
    df = df[(left <= df.left) & (top <= df.top) & (right >= df.right) & (bottom >= df.bottom)]
    
    df.sort_values(['top', 'left'], ignore_index=True, inplace=True)
    
    return(" ".join(df.words.tolist()))
```

Use `apply` to apply the function for each row.

```
df_cells['Words'] = df_cells.apply(lambda row: filter_text(**row.to_dict()), axis=1)

df_cells

   left   top  right  bottom            Words
0  1095  1247   1158    1273      Hello world
1   257  1148    616    1176  have a nice day
```